# Display an specific HTML text in batch file

Tags: html, batch-file, cmd

I'm making a batch program to show recent updates based on a .HTML document. I wanted it to read exactly the "**October 26, 2022**" part (seen below), completely ignoring the other codes and put it in a variable.

Part of the document I want to read is based on this:

```
<li><span>Current version:</span><span>**October 26, 2022**</span></li>
```

I would implement it inside this batch code with the **!CurrentVersionDate!** variable

```
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) DO (
call :GetLastModifiedDate "!File[%%i]!" LastModifiedDate
    echo ::------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo DLL File: "!file[%%i]!"
    echo Version date: "!LastModifiedDate!"
    echo Current version: "!CurrentVersionDate!"
    echo ::------------------------------------------------------------------
)
```

As I said, I wanted it to be displayed without the HTML codes, like

```
::------------------------------------------------------------------
DLL File: "!file[%%i]!"
Version date: "!LastModifiedDate!"
Current version: October 26, 2022
::------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, I tried to use **`for /F "skip=385 delims=" %%i in (page.html) DO set "LastModifiedDate=%%i`**, it shows the following result:

```
Current version: Current version:</span> <span>  October 26, 2022  </span></li>
```

I also tried **`FINDSTR /C:"Current version" page.html`**, but it was useless, because it showed the same thing and I didn't have the variable in my hands.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should try with powershell using regex to extract it like that :
`$testText = '<span>Current version:</span> <span>  October 26, 2022  </span></li>';$pattern = '((?<=\<span\>).+?(?=<\/span>))';[regex]::Matches($testText, $pattern).Groups[2].Value.Trim()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Using PowerShell and RegEx to extract text between delimiters](https://powershellone.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/using-powershell-and-regex-to-extract-text-between-delimiters/), You can give a try with this batch example that uses regex :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Using PowerShell and RegEx to extract text between delimiters
@for /f "tokens=*delims=" %%a in ('Type page.html ^| FINDSTR /I /C:"Current Version"') do (
    @for /f "delims=" %%D in (
        'Powershell -C "[regex]::Matches('%%a','((?<=\<span\>).+?(?=<\/span>))').Groups[2].Value.Trim()"'
        ) Do (
            Set "CurrentVersion=%%D"
        )
)
echo Current Version : %CurrentVersion%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:: %1=quoted filename
:: %2=variablename to return value
:lastmodifieddate
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e in (%1) do (
 set "#line=%%e"
 if "!#line!" neq "!#line:<li><span>Current version:</span><span>=!" (
  set "#line=!#line:*<li><span>Current version:</span><span>=!"
  for /f "delims=*<" %%y in ("!#line!") do set "%2=%%y"&goto :eof
 )
)
goto :eof
```

Assuming `delayedexpansion` is in effect,

For each line in the file, set `#line` to its content, see whether the `...Current version...` string is on the line; if so, delete that portion, then use the result, with `*` and `<` as delimiters to extract the first remaining token and return it.

It's not clear whether the `**` in the sample is literal or an attempt to highlight the required string.